# React Webpack 4 Resolve Alias

Tags: reactjs, webpack, import, webpack-4, resolve

I'm having difficulty getting resolve alias to work in my React app using WebPack, and everything I've tried from google results don't seem to make a difference.

Here is my resolve from webpack.

C:\website\webpack.config.js

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
        apiAlias: path.resolve(__dirname, '/app/services/api/')
    }
}
```

Here is C:\website\app\components\Accounts\Accounts.js

```
import ApiAccounts from '/apiAlias/ApiAccounts.js';
```

and I have a file located in C:\website\app\services\api\ApiAccounts.js
Changing the above line to the below works:

```
import ApiAccounts from '../../services/api/ApiAccounts.js';
```

For fullness, here are my webpack dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
 }
```

and yet I keep getting the error of

> ERROR in ./app/components/Accounts/Accounts.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/apiAlias/ApiAccounts.js' in 'C:\website\app\components\Accounts'

Can anyone see anything obvious as to what I'm missing, or should try to try and get this working, or even if there is a way to debug webpack to see what path it is actually using if the alias is actually kicking in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only thing I was missing was the dot before /app!

```
apiAlias: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/services/api/')
```

Comment: A bit late, but I don't think that's what solved your issue. Looking at https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths, path.resolve works fine with or without the '.' prefix. I think Nikita's answer is more likely.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is remove the first `'/'` in your ApiAccounts import:

```
import ApiAccounts from 'apiAlias/ApiAccounts.js';
```

This way your import path start with the key in your alias object, which in your case is `apiAlias`.