# Importing nested SCSS module fails (Gatsby)

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

In Gatsby, I'm trying to import a (nested) SCSS module into a component (`project-card.js`), but getting an error that I can't solve. I'm using `gatsby-plugin-alias-imports`, and my file hierarchy is set up as:

```
| --> components
|     --> project
|         --> project-card.js
| --> styles
|     --> project
|         --> project-card.module.scss
```

When I attempt `import styles from "@styles/project/project-card.module.scss"`, I get a `Module not found: Can't resolve {filepath}` error.

However, if I move the SCSS module up one level in the file hierarchy (directly under `/styles`) and use `import styles from "@styles/project-card.module.scss"`, the compiler runs and I see the styles as expected.

Am I missing something in terms of config that's causing the `Module not found` error?

——————————

Edit: As requested, `gatsby-plugin-alias-imports` configuration:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {
        resolve: `gatsby-plugin-alias-imports`,
            options: {
                alias: {
                    "@components": path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
                    "@images": path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/images'),
                    "@pages": path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages'),
                    "@styles": path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles')
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How have you used `gatsby-plugin-alias-imports` within your config

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri - just updated the post with my config above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50784879/5385381), what happens if you try:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {
        resolve: `gatsby-plugin-alias-imports`,
            options: {
                alias: {
                    "@components": path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
                    "@images": path.resolve(__dirname, './src/images'),
                    "@pages": path.resolve(__dirname, './src/pages'),
                    "@styles": path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styles')
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```